# Java File IO scan into variables

Tags: java

this is basically my first true Java assignment and I've hit a brick wall. I basically wrote my entire project as if the user were to input the information into the program. upon rereading the assignment I saw that we are to input the info from a .txt file in the following format:

1.17 12 15( and then sort them)

1. 7 54 9873 1867 4425 878 365 783 (where the first number n indicates how many n will folow)
2. 4 (flyods triangle problem)
3. 20 (fizz buzz problem)

I have all of the code written to solve these parts of the project but am completely stuck on how to implement the numbers from the .txt file. I am not asking for code merely some advice on how you guys might go about doing so/

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunTime {
public static void main(String args[])
{
int n, num = 1, c, d;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
n = in.nextInt();

for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
{
for ( d = 1 ; d <= c ; d++ )
{
System.out.print(num+" ");
num++;
}

System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, reading from a file is exactly like reading from the terminal. Instead of reading from `System.in`, read from a file that you open with something like `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Ok so something like //read(byte[] b)// would work? If thats the case Im just confused as how to call the int within the other parts of the program.

Comment: Not quite, you don't need to call `read()` yourself. Just change your program so that: (1) you open your file and save a reference (eg. call it `infile`), and (2) use `infile` instead of `System.in` throughout the rest of your program.

Comment: is this what youre talking about? [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/fileinputstream_read.htm)

Comment: You could use `read()` if you like, but that's doing it the hard way. The key point here is that `System.in` works *exactly like a file*, only it reads from the terminal instead of from a file. So the solution is to use your own file instead of `System.in` (which you have presumably already used in your code somewhere). Posting some of your code at this point would help a lot.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty much what I expected to see. Do just what I said, open a file using `FileInputStream`, save the result in a variable, and then use that variable where you currently have `System.in`. That's all you need to do.